# How to open the URL for authentication inside the iFrame?

Tags: add-in, outlook-addin

I am trying to use a rest API for authentication in my outlook add-in but it is being redirected to a separate browser window instead of rendering in the Iframe and control never comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of security constraints you cannot implement the OAUTH flow within the addin sandboxed iFrame, so the popup window is a necessary workaround.

Here is the [best solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/08/10/connecting-to-office-365-from-an-office-add-in/) to achieve the OAUTH flow in popup.

Microsoft is well aware of the problem and has started to work on a [dialogAPI](http://simonjaeger.com/lets-have-a-dialog-about-the-dialog-api/) that avoid popup window (that may be turned off).

EDIT (September 2016):

At Keluro we released an open source code sample to leverage the sign-in technicalities. It is used more for connecting to Azure AD/Office 365 but the client side using dialogApi and the popup as a fall back can be reused